# CSS semi-dynamic width

Tags: css, width

I have some keywords that show up in separate inline-block elements with 10%(=80px) width. Currently I am setting `overflow:hidden;` for longer words, but it's not a good practice. I want that if some of these keywords are longer than usual, their parent div (the one with currently 10% width applied to) should be twice its size: 160px. I wonder if this can be solved with CSS3 only.

I'll try to explain it visually:

`+__80px__+__80px__+__80px__+`

`+__text__+`

`+__longer text____+`

`+______way longer text_____+`

instead of

`+overflow hi+` or `+random width to fit text+`

If the text does not fit in 80px, its container should be 160px. That simple. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way to do this in CSS, but with a little JavaScript magic you can make it work:

```
// assuming all elements are in a container with id="container"...
var qsa = document.getElementById('container').children, l = qsa.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( qsa[i].scrollWidth > 240) {
        // this one handles REALLY long text by cutting them off with "..."
        qsa[i].style.textOverflow = "ellipsis";
        qsa[i].style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    }
    if( qsa[i].scrollWidth > 160) qsa[i].style.width = "240px";
    else if( qsa[i].scrollWidth > 80) qsa[i].style.width = "160px";
    // else do nothing, leave the deafult 80 width
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know if I successfully implement this to the keyword listing script.